# Android Changing dynamic view with radiogroups

Tags: java, android, listeners

how can i dynamically update my layout based on what radio button is selected?
Currently i have all my code within the oncreate and it seems to only check once to see which radio button is selected, but how can i make it update each time it is changed?

here is my code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  LinearLayout mainLinear = new LinearLayout(this);
  mainLinear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
  LinearLayout ButtonLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
  ButtonLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
  ButtonLayout.setPadding(120, 15, 0, 0);
  mainLinear.addView(ButtonLayout);
  Button deleteSelectedButton = new Button(this);
  deleteSelectedButton.setText("Delete Selected");
  Button backButton = new Button(this);
  backButton.setText("Back");
  ButtonLayout.addView(deleteSelectedButton);
  ButtonLayout.addView(backButton);
  LinearLayout deleteAppointmentLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
  deleteAppointmentLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
  mainLinear.addView(deleteAppointmentLayout);
  TextView dayLabel = new TextView(this);
  dayLabel.setText("Days");
  dayLabel.setPadding(220, 10, 0, 0);
  dayLabel.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
  dayLabel.setTextSize(15);
  deleteAppointmentLayout.addView(dayLabel);
  RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
  radioGroup.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
  radioGroup.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
  deleteAppointmentLayout.addView(radioGroup);
  RadioButton mondayRadioButton = new RadioButton(this);
  RadioButton tuesdayRadioButton = new RadioButton(this);
  RadioButton wednesdayRadioButton = new RadioButton(this);
  RadioButton thursdayRadioButton = new RadioButton(this);
  RadioButton fridayRadioButton = new RadioButton(this);
  mondayRadioButton.setText("Mon");
  tuesdayRadioButton.setText("Tue");
  wednesdayRadioButton.setText("Wed");
  thursdayRadioButton.setText("Thu");
  fridayRadioButton.setText("Fri");
  mondayRadioButton.setTextSize(12);
  tuesdayRadioButton.setTextSize(12);
  wednesdayRadioButton.setTextSize(12);
  thursdayRadioButton.setTextSize(12);
  fridayRadioButton.setTextSize(12);
  mondayRadioButton.setChecked(true);
  mondayRadioButton.setId(1);
  tuesdayRadioButton.setId(2);
  wednesdayRadioButton.setId(3);
  thursdayRadioButton.setId(4);
  fridayRadioButton.setId(5);
  //OnClickListener radlistener;
  //radioGroup.setOnClickListener(radlistener);
  radioGroup.addView(mondayRadioButton);
  radioGroup.addView(tuesdayRadioButton);
  radioGroup.addView(wednesdayRadioButton);
  radioGroup.addView(thursdayRadioButton);
  radioGroup.addView(fridayRadioButton);
  CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
  ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
  mainLinear.addView(scrollView);
  LinearLayout deleteAppointmentsLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
  deleteAppointmentsLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
  scrollView.addView(deleteAppointmentsLayout);
  APData = new AppointmentDataSource(this);
  APData.open();
  //printf("Go to here");
  List < Appointment > appointments = APData.retrieveAllAppointments();
  APData.close();
  String time, duration, description, boxText;
  long id;
  int loop = 0;
  if (mondayRadioButton.isChecked()) {
    deleteAppointmentsLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (Iterator < Appointment > i = appointments.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
      Appointment item = i.next();
      if (item.getDay() == 1) {
        System.out.println("fucken did work");
        id = item.getId();
        time = item.getTime();
        duration = item.getDuration();
        description = item.getDescription();
        boxText = time + ", " + duration + ", " + description;
        checkBox.setText(boxText);
        checkBox.setId((int) id);
        deleteAppointmentsLayout.addView(checkBox);
      } else {
        System.out.println("fucken didnt work");
      }
    }
  }
  if (tuesdayRadioButton.isChecked()) {
    deleteAppointmentsLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (Iterator < Appointment > i = appointments.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
      Appointment item = i.next();
      if (item.getDay() == 2) {
        id = item.getId();
        time = item.getTime();
        duration = item.getDuration();
        description = item.getDescription();
        boxText = time + ", " + duration + ", " + description;
        checkBox.setText(boxText);
        checkBox.setId((int) id);
        deleteAppointmentsLayout.addView(checkBox);
      } else {}
    }
  }
  if (wednesdayRadioButton.isChecked()) {
    deleteAppointmentsLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (Iterator < Appointment > i = appointments.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
      Appointment item = i.next();
      if (item.getDay() == 3) {
        id = item.getId();
        time = item.getTime();
        duration = item.getDuration();
        description = item.getDescription();
        boxText = time + ", " + duration + ", " + description;
        checkBox.setText(boxText);
        checkBox.setId((int) id);
        deleteAppointmentsLayout.addView(checkBox);
      } else {}
    }
  }
  if (thursdayRadioButton.isChecked()) {
    deleteAppointmentsLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (Iterator < Appointment > i = appointments.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
      Appointment item = i.next();
      if (item.getDay() == 4) {
        id = item.getId();
        time = item.getTime();
        duration = item.getDuration();
        description = item.getDescription();
        boxText = time + ", " + duration + ", " + description;
        checkBox.setText(boxText);
        checkBox.setId((int) id);
        deleteAppointmentsLayout.addView(checkBox);
      } else {}
    }
  }
  if (fridayRadioButton.isChecked()) {
    deleteAppointmentsLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (Iterator < Appointment > i = appointments.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
      Appointment item = i.next();
      if (item.getDay() == 5) {
        id = item.getId();
        time = item.getTime();
        duration = item.getDuration();
        description = item.getDescription();
        boxText = time + ", " + duration + ", " + description;
        checkBox.setText(boxText);
        checkBox.setId((int) id);
        deleteAppointmentsLayout.addView(checkBox);
      } else {}
    }
  }
  this.setContentView(mainLinear);
  deleteSelectedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
    Override
    public void onClick(View view) {}
  });
  backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
    Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      finish();
    }
  });
}
```

updated code (wants me to change all variables to FINAL and resulting in time duration description and boxtext to error with "The final local variable description cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type" <- only does that when i make checkBox a final aswell)

```
mondayRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {

              if(mondayRadioButton.isChecked()){
                deleteAppointmentsLayout.removeAllViews();
            for(Iterator<Appointment> i = appointments.iterator(); i.hasNext();){ 
                 Appointment item = i.next();
                    if(item.getDay() == 1){
                        System.out.println("fucken did work");
                        id = item.getId();
                        time = item.getTime();
                        duration = item.getDuration();
                        description = item.getDescription();
                        boxText = time + ", " + duration + ", " + description;
                        checkBox.setText(boxText);
                        checkBox.setId((int) id);
                        deleteAppointmentsLayout.addView(checkBox);

                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("fucken didnt work");
                    }
            }
            }
          }

        });
```

Comment: That's an awful lot of code to sift through for a small problem. Mind cutting it down to only the relevant bits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have write the above code in Oncreate, it will work for the first time when you enter into screen, later it won't, so you need to Execute the above code when an event triggers so

For individual radio buttons set `onClickLister`

```
 radiobutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {

                   //your code here
          }

        });
```

And for the group `setOnCheckedChangeListener` like this

```
grp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
                  //your code here

            }
        });
```

post code inside of the above listeners

You can also use onCheckChangeListener on radiobutton

```
radiobtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // your code here

            }
        });
```

**Edit:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText message, password, username;  // these are called fields
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//instantiate like this
        username = new EditText(this);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
}
}
```

Comment: When i use the Group method "radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() { and place the if code within that it just seems to error everything.

Comment: @user2253722 Post only relavent code that need to be executed when radio button is checked. Let me see your updated code, post it

Comment: @user2253722 Declare your those variables which needs to be final as `Fields`, i.e declare them globally and get their reference in `onCreate`

Comment: so like this? private LinearLayout deleteAppointmentsLayout;
 private List<Appointment> appointments;
 private String time, duration, description, boxText;
 private long id;

Comment: Awesome thank! thats working now!! But just came up across another problem. so far when its generating the code for the dynamic layout. if a certain day has more than 1 checkbox to generate it gives an error and crashes "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

Comment: @user2253722 you need to create check box instance everytime when you are adding new checkbox. i.e set `checkBox=new CheckBox(this)` every time for new checkbox. Don't forgot to accept this as answer if it helps.

Comment: Yeah i attempted to mark as answer but i require 15 reputation before i can give you a +rep :(

Comment: @user2253722 nope that is vote.. but there is a right symbol beside that if you observe carefully. like checkbox you need to mark it

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement an "onCheckedChanged()" on your RadioGroup, then updating information in your layout, or even inflating different layout based on checked radio.